# why don't solve that responsive web is different local and server

Tags: java, html, responsive

http://api.vankow.com/file/images/8.9%20%EC%B6%9C%EA%B3%A0%EC%A0%95%EC%82%B0.HTML
-> loading page to server is not working responsive

but open to local page is working responsive. i don't understand

file:///C:/Users/mega79/8.9%20%EC%B6%9C%EA%B3%A0%EC%A0%95%EC%82%B0.HTML

Comment: Your question seems quite incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your img DOM element doesn't have width property,
which will load image source's natural width and height.
that is why your img element was exceeding the layout.
you can simply add style width: 100%; to your img DOM element

Comment: Oh, now that you give this answer I see that the OP is trying to ask.

Comment: what is op?????

Comment: It's the person who asked the question.  "OP" basically means "Original Poster" (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/whats-stackexchange-ese-for-op)

Comment: i add style width:100% but still not working....T.T

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem!  I do it!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width"/>        
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<style>
  body {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
  }
</style>    
<script>
  $(function() {
        $("#post_content img, .resizablebox").each(function() {
            var oImgWidth = $(this).width();
            var oImgHeight = $(this).height();
            $(this).css({
                'max-width':oImgWidth+'px',
                'max-height':oImgHeight+'px',
                'width':'100%',
                'height':'100%'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<title>VANKOW ERP 메뉴얼입니다.</title>
<h1>8.별도 - 8.9 출고정산</h1>        
<div>
  <p>
    <img src="http://api.vankow.com/file/images/image045.png"/   style="maxwidth:900px; max-height: 900px; width: 100%; height:100%;">
  </p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```